# What are the Compatibility Levels of Arcana with the Party?

Tags: persona-2-eternal-punishment

So, I'm playing *Shin Megami Tensei Persona 2: Eternal Punishment* for Playstation 1 and I am noticing that unlike *Shin Megami Tensei Persona 2: Innocent Sin* on the PSP, Compatibility isn't exactly colour coded. I can still tell when a Persona isn't compatible with a character since they can't be paired but I have noticed that a persona that can be paired with more than 1 character can have varied SP Levels between characters.

Now, in a way I could use Innocent Sin on the PSP to work out Tatsuya's and Maya's Comparability with each of the Tarot Arcana and possibly *Shin Megami Tensei Persona 1* on PSP for Kei and Eriko but I have a feeling that they won't be the exact same (and I'm even more doubtful that Kei's and Eriko's would be the same) not to mention this won't help with the new playable characters Ulala, Katsuya, Baofu.

So, I am wondering: what are the Compatibility Levels for Maya, Ulala, Katsuya, Baofu, Tatsyua, Kei and Eriko with each of the Tarot Arcana?